# Can anyone tell me meaning of this line

Tags: meaning

A man who  suffers before it  is necessary, suffers  more than is  necessary

Comment: Worrying about tomorrow simply ruins today as well as tomorrow. If something bad *does* happen tomorrow.. well, you’ve lost that day. But you don’t need to lose *today* too by worrying about it. Let the future take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

*A man who suffers before it is necessary, suffers more than is necessary.*

From [Philosiblog.com](https://philosiblog.com/2011/08/13/a-man-who-suffers-before-it-is-necessary-suffers-more-than-is-necessary/)

> If you are suffering before it is necessary, you are anticipating the
>   suffering. That means you suffer before than it actually is necessary,
>   and therefore, longer than necessary.

This reminds me of another phrase: *Today is the tomorrow you worried about yesterday.*

Controlling emotion, if you can, keep it from gaining on the problems Keep calm and seek logical solutions.  Do not procrastinate. As the Brits say, “keep calm and carry on”. Easier said than cone as anxiety/worry are common to the human condition.  Some prods one to action. Balance is the key.